# how to install gems in home dir?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, home-directory

I'm installing gems in my `$HOME` directory

```
$ cat .gemrc 
-----------------------------------
gemhome: ~/.gems

gempath: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
-----------------------------------

$ gem install rspec
installs rspec in ~/.gems/gems/rspec-*

$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

diff-lcs (1.2.4)
rspec (2.13.0)
rspec-core (2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1)

$ rspec test_rspec.rb 
cant find rspec -- apparently its not in $PATH

$ gem uninstall rspec
INFO:  gem "rspec" is not installed
```

can anyone help me? i'm not using rvm, i'm trying to understand these tools first.

thanks

UPDATE:

```
env | grep GEM
```

returns nothing

```
gem env
```

RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-05-15 patchlevel 429) [i486-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: ~/.gems/
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: ~/.gems/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - x86-linux
- GEM PATHS:

  - ~/.gems/
  - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 ~/.gems/
- GEM CONFIGURATION:

  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :benchmark => false
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - "gemhome" => "~/.gems/"
  - "gempath" => "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 ~/.gems/"
- REMOTE SOURCES:

  - http://rubygems.org/

Comment: please post the output of `env | grep GEM`. I suspect that your environment variables `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` are not set up correctly. See also: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3